# ValidateAntiForgeryToken purpose, explanation and example

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Could you explain [ValidateAntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) purpose and show me example about `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` in MVC 4?

I could not find any examples which explain this attribute?

Comment: Check this post http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/securing_all_forms_using_antiforgerytoken

Comment: By the way, I really don't understand why MS haven't made it possible to put this right inside the `.BeginForm` helper. So this thing is there automatically, like in Rails

Answer (score 389, accepted):

MVC's anti-forgery support writes a unique value to an HTTP-only cookie and then the same value is written to the form. When the page is submitted, an error is raised if the cookie value doesn't match the form value.

It's important to note that the feature prevents [cross site request forgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). That is, a form from another site that posts to your site in an attempt to submit hidden content using an authenticated user's credentials. The attack involves tricking the logged in user into submitting a form, or by simply programmatically triggering a form when the page loads.

The feature doesn't prevent any other type of data forgery or tampering based attacks.

To use it, decorate the action method or controller with the [`ValidateAntiForgeryToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute.aspx) attribute and place a call to [`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken.aspx) in the forms posting to the method.

Comment: Judging by the way MVC CRUD Templates implement this, this does not appear to be correct. If you look at the forms using it that it generates, you'll see: @Html.AntiForgeryToken() inside each form. The VSDoc for this says it generates a hidden form field with the anti-forgery token in it. It seems clear it's actually a hidden form field, and not a cookie. Is there a separate scenario where it is a cookie?

Comment: @Chris It's both. As per my answer: "writes a unique value to an HTTP-only cookie and then *the same value is written to the form*"

Comment: Ah, missed that detail. You are correct - AntiForgeryToken article: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: Why isn't this set by default?

Comment: Documentation links would be nice!

Comment: @TheOptimusPrimus The reference to the class name in the last paragraph links to the MSDN docs.

Comment: @Christian because it is not Ruby on Rails. ;-)

Comment: @Martin Capodici i'd say not every web-site needs this kind of validation which costs some additional processing.

Comment: It seems that the form __RequestVerificationToken and cookie __RequestVerificationToken are not the same, they work as a pair.

Comment: I got a question: And in which cases should I use that key?

Comment: so would it be fair to say that if your site doesnt allow CORS then theres no benefit from the anti forgery token?

Comment: @rdans Not at all, CORS and CSRF are entirely different. CORS is for allowing other domains to access APIs on your server, CSRF is about making sure that a form post came from the page you expected it to.

Comment: Further to my previous comment: CORS is only enforced on cross-origin `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` requests. Form posts, images, and script/css are all excluded from CORS and thus can be used to exploit your existing cookies on another domain.

Comment: In .NET Core It is possible to configure so that all requests would validate anti forgery token by default by adding a global filter `services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); });`

Answer (score 62):

The basic purpose of ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute is to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks.

A cross-site request forgery is an attack in which a harmful script element, malicious command, or code is sent from the browser of a trusted user. For more information on this please visit
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages.

It is simple to use, you need to decorate method with ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute as below:

```
[HttpPost]  
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
public ActionResult CreateProduct(Product product)  
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)  
  {
    //your logic 
  }
  return View(ModelName);
}
```

It is derived from System.Web.Mvc namespace.

And in your view, add this code to add the token so it is used to validate the form upon submission.

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: Yes you are right,you need to call @Html.AntiForgeryToken() from your form and add the ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute to the action method that you want to protect.

Answer (score 19):

In ASP.Net Core anti forgery token is automatically added to forms, so you don't need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` if you use razor form element or if you use IHtmlHelper.BeginForm and if the form's method isn't GET.

It will generate input element for your form similar to this:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
       value="CfDJ8HSQ_cdnkvBPo-jales205VCq9ISkg9BilG0VXAiNm3Fl5Lyu_JGpQDA4_CLNvty28w43AL8zjeR86fNALdsR3queTfAogif9ut-Zd-fwo8SAYuT0wmZ5eZUYClvpLfYm4LLIVy6VllbD54UxJ8W6FA">
```

And when user submits form this token is verified on server side if validation is enabled.

`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute can be used against actions. Requests made to actions that have this filter applied are blocked unless the request includes a valid antiforgery token.

`[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` attribute can be used against controllers. This attribute works identically to the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute, except that it doesn't require tokens for requests made using the following HTTP methods:
`GET HEAD OPTIONS TRACE`

Additional information:
[learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery)