# Is the antiforgery token function safe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I have one question about Mvc antiforgerytoken

In mvc razor page, we can place code: `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside the form, it will generate a token, this token will be fill into a hidden input field like:

```
 <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
 value="6I2CsrmAhiDlHewQ4q4khXAENgaa66kDiGwHgaN5DV0f4W2_c2nyVA-q2OCingcgKLPNhSSeyuS_WaTmAGzpo3F5gUq9Wx89iXH1ujq6ZwGG5rO8v_F-4hYj5gEVZ1-E-DpxkcO7zIjMUKVH1bjPMo7Ot3UJHLl5r9isfCLyiOA1">
```

**Question**:
I can easily create a request to download this mvc razor page to get token from "__RequestVerificationToken" field, then post bad data to attack specify server.
Is this means antiforgery token function also not safe???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe. Placing an anti forgery token to the form also creates a cookie named  **__RequestVerificationToken** with the same token. This cookie is also validated to verify the request. Since the attacker can't add cookies to application domain, it can't pass this validation.

Steve Sanderson has a nice [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/) that explains it in detail.

Comment: the post says:This is an authorization filter that checks that:
The incoming request has a cookie called __RequestVerificationToken
The incoming request has a Request.Form entry called __RequestVerificationToken
These cookie and Request.Form values match.   But actually, i can submit the data even i did not have cookie

Comment: <form name="badform" method="post" action="http://local.test.com//Home/Text">
        <input type="hidden" name="Notice" id="Notice" value="bad data" />
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="6I2CsrmAhiDlHewQ4q4khXAENgaa66kDiGwHgaN5DV0f4W2_c2nyVA-q2OCingcgKLPNhSSeyuS_WaTmAGzpo3F5gUq9Wx89iXH1ujq6ZwGG5rO8v_F-4hYj5gEVZ1-E-DpxkcO7zIjMUKVH1bjPMo7Ot3UJHLl5r9isfCLyiOA1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>  ----  you can see i got the token , and just put into my html page, submit to other site, and it's working.

Comment: @Dragon Can you show Text action method in HomeController?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Text()
        {
            ViewBag.Notice = Request.Form["Notice"].ToString();
            return View();
        }

Comment: @Dragon You accepted the answer. Does that mean you identified the problem? The code you posted should throw an exception when the data is posted.

Comment: Not totally, the problem now is that while i'm testing two different page from two domain in the same browser, Page1(from Domain1) can submit data with token to Page2(from Domain2), but it won't working if i open them with two different browser, there must be something relate to cookie, but i can not solve it now

Comment: It seems they are sharing cookies within one browser, i can see cookie '__RequestVerificationToken' in Domain2, but not in Domain1（contains attack page）

Comment: I would like to share a post with you, it's very nice  http://adam.kahtava.com/journal/2009/11/25/what-are-anti-cross-site-request-forgery-tokens-and-what-are-they-good-for/

Comment: @Dragon That explains it I guess. I thought your console app was only doing the parsing and you were posting the data from the browser. You may want to take a look [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33969/205859) for request throttling.

Answer (score 1):

The [AntiForgeryToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is meant to ensure that cross-site request forgery attacks ([CSRFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention)) can't succeed, and the token does that: if the request to the form's target came from another site, it would not have the correct token, and so the request would be immediately rejected. If the other site has to first contact your site to get the token, then it might as well have been going through your site to begin with.

Comment: It's not the only validation. Users can turn off sending referrer headers

Comment: Yes, i mean other site has to first download page from my site, then he will got the correct token, submit his bad data with the correct token, i did a test, copy the token from my site, then put this token into a  html page, with one submit button and one hidden value, and it can be submit successful.

Comment: @Dragon The corresponding cookie (as mentioned in Ufuk's answer) is supposed to prevent that.

Comment: @Dragon Keep in mind that you will create the cookie if you display the form before. Use private browsing to display the form.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Sorry, i'm a little confuse, my question: 1.Use console application, create a request to download page1 from site1  2.Get token from the result of page1   3. Submit data to the action of page1 with token.

Comment: and i did not see cookie been created after i visit my page

Comment: @Dragon Do you have [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621934/validateantiforgerytoken-purpose-explanation-and-example) on your action method that responds to POST request?