# Windows authentication to Azure AD, and .NET 4.5 to 4.7. Error - the required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, owin

I have changed the authentication from Windows authentication to Azure AD on a legacy application and also upgraded .NET framework from 4.5 to 4.7.

Code implementation can be found

here [How to integrate Azure AD Authentication in ASP.NET (on .NET 4.7) Web application using Owin without enablling Anonymouse Authentication in Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420879/how-to-integrate-azure-ad-authentication-in-asp-net-on-net-4-7-web-applicatio)

Now where I have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` (in the controller) and `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` (in the view), I am getting the errors shown here.

In the view I have code:

[image]

and I am getting this error

> Additional information: A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier, it can be configured by setting the static property AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.

**Solution:** I put this line in `Global.cs`:

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

REF: [Anti-forgery token issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977833/anti-forgery-token-issues)

But in my controller where I have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, I am getting this error in my event viewer:

> Timestamp: 5/11/2023 11:03:36 p.m.
> Message: HandlingInstanceID: 9a40af6a-2fa8-4abc-9699-b5000b9ef309
> An exception of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException' occurred and was caught.
>
> Type : System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
> Message : The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
> Source : System.Web.WebPages

What do I need to change to fix this?

REF: [The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759102/the-required-anti-forgery-cookie-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present)

Comment: You're conflating two separate kinds of anti-forgery tokens. The error message from AAD has nothing to do with ASP.NET `<form>` `AntiforgeryToken`.