# Is ValidateAntiForgeryToken autoimplemented with POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm reading POST is considered secure and GET no, and that we should implement [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] in every action of every controller.

The question is: need I use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] data annotation when I use [POST]?

Comment: No, it doesn't auto-implemented, you need to put an attribute on your ActionResult. check this answer for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622061/713789

Comment: Not yet in official stable branch but propably it will be from 2.0 https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/3688

Answer (score 3):

It's off by default.
There's good reason for this. Not every POST has to come from a form (especially true since your question is tagged `asp.net-core`)

You should decorate your controller action with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Post(Model model)
{
    // ... etc
}
```

If you're using the form tag helper, it will automatically add the anti forgery token for you, into the `<form>` markup.

The markup generated will look something like:

```
<form action="/MyController" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="fhTFfhkKNsdfhYazFtN6c4YbZAmsEwG0srqlUqqloi/OIJOIJoijojhishg" />
    <!-- rest of form here -->
</form>
```

Note: You can also manually enable/disable `__RequestVerificationToken` generation using the form helper tags:

```
<form
 asp-controller="MyController" 
 asp-action="MyAction" 
 asp-antiforgery="false" 
 method="post">
```

Comment: I have a web API. My client is Angular4.

Comment: @JohnDoe good for you. Why have you tagged your question with `asp.net-core-mvc`?!

Comment: The web API uses MVC.