# How to call async Task from ajax aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am using asp.net core and I am calling async task `ActionResult` method from ajax. Its is running fine on local host but after hosting on IIS it throw 500 status code error.

**But it is not calling this method is ajax code**

> This is ajax method:

```
$('.Savebtn').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Testing", "Home")',
                        data: "Test data",
                        type: 'POST', //POST if you want to save, GET if you want to fetch data from server
                        success: function (obj) {
                            // here comes your response after calling the server
                            alert('Suceeded');
                        },
                        error: function (obj) {
                            alert('Something happened');
                        }
                    });
            });
```

**This is Controller method:**

```
   [HttpPost]

   public async Task<IActionResult> Testing()
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            try
            {
               return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

         }
            return View();
   }
```

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I13lI.png)

Comment: Check your browser console and post what console errors you get.

Comment: yes i checked it comes 500 status code error

Comment: In local host does it hits action method and do you want  `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` ?

Comment: Pass token into request 
var form = $('form');
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token},

Comment: i don't want to use [ValidateAntiForgeryToek] actually it is my testing method because it is not calling after hosting on IIS.

Comment: yes , In local host it hits actionMethod

Comment: In localhost also, It will only be hit if you have removed `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute totally or you should  generate cookie value for `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In Startup.cs file add service like this:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "RequestVerificationToken");
```

In your cshtml file add:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/home/Demo1',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

And your method in Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Demo1()
{
    //your code
    return new JsonResult(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` remove it and it will work. If you want it, then you have to pass the auto generated cookie value to validate as mentioned below, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621934/validateantiforgerytoken-purpose-explanation-and-example).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Testing()
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      try
      {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        return Ok();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

       return NotFound();

      }

    }
       return View();
 }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }

    <button class="Savebtn btn btn-success">Save</button>
```

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('.Savebtn').click(function () {
            var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Testing", "Home")',
                data: {
                    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    data: "Test data"
                },
                type: 'POST', //POST if you want to save, GET if you want to fetch data from server
                success: function (obj) {
                    // here comes your response after calling the server
                    alert('Suceeded');
                },
                error: function (obj) {
                    alert('Something happened');
                }
            });
    });

    })

</script>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Hey Mr.  Nimesh Gami  bro. again i have problem to call that actionMethod on IIS but it is running fine on local host. i attched my error image. please check it

Comment: Welcome to SO, If you want to comment to Nimesh Gami then use @ check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) post to know how to reply to a specific user. Coming to your error, It gives 500 error because ,you are using `return NotFound();` instead use `return Ok();`.

Answer (score 0):

First change the URL to like 'Testing/Home' and Make sure you're passing data because if you don't it might throw 500 status code error.

In my case I wasn't passing any data I mean I was sending an empty form that was why. I thought it might help someone.