# Implementing AntiForgery Token on ASP.NET 4.6 WebForms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, antiforgerytoken

As title i'm trying to implement an AntiForgery Token in Asp.net 4.6 framework.
I've a Site.Master page and i'm studying this article to adapt on my site
[How To Fix Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) using Microsoft .Net ViewStateUserKey and Double Submit Cookie](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf)

Now i've converted from c# to vb.net and i put the code in my masterpage.

By compiler notes me that

```
Page.PreLoad += AddressOf master_Page_PreLoad
```

is a event and i can't declare directly.

Anyway i don't understand if it's right way to solve problem or exists another way to follow.

Comment: The original blog post seems to be no longer available, but the sample code appear to be available in this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353249/421356

Answer (score 1):

Solved. With

```
AddHandler Page.PreLoad, AddressOf master_Page_PreLoad
```

instead of

```
Page.PreLoad += AddressOf master_Page_PreLoad
```

Another things about the goal "Implementing AntiForgery Token on ASP.NET 4.6 WebForm" in the webmethod i had to use

HttpContext.Current.Session("CookieName") to verify token generated on Page_Init because in webmethos you can't use ViewState.

To use Sessione in web method, in declaration of web method you must define EnableSession as

```
 <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True), ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)> _
Public Function GetFunction(myjson As String) As String.....
```